# MKMApview User live moving animation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cllocationmanager, nsurlsession

I have two modules (driver and customer) in my iOS application. Here customer wants to know where the driver is right now and customer has to see the driver movement in mapview.

So What I did is,

1.In **Driver module** - I will update driver current location into my server once in a 2 seconds using NSURLSession.

2.In **Customer Module** - I will take driver current location from server  once in a 2 seconds and I will display it into map.

What my question is ,

1.Will it affect my application performance if I call API(to get and post driver location) once in a 2 seconds ?

2.Is there any other option to do this ?

Comment: Ya if you call API in your application the memory issue you face and the load of your application increase and its also possible that your application is crash

Comment: I have done similar kind of application with use of Sockets.
For backend you will need Node.js